How to exclude an element from view transitions?
I have an v17.3 Angular App and enabled view transitions using the withViewTransitions() function.
Now, how can I exclude one specific element from the default (root) view transitions?
::view-transition-old(root),
::view-transition-new(root)

I already tried to set the view-transition-name style property of that element to none as mentioned in the docs, disabled animations with animation: none; and set mix-blend-mode: normal;. But the element still gets animated.
Edit: I'm using Google Chrome so the feature should be available.
Edit2:
As workaround I can disable view transitions for an element by setting the view-transition-name to disabled and providing this css:
::view-transition-group(disabled),
::view-transition-old(disabled),
::view-transition-new(disabled) {
    animation-duration: 0s !important;
}


Your workaround works out fine. You maybe want to use it to use it to answer your own question.

It seems that the workaround shown in the question is a suitable solution to the problem.
You can disable view transitions for an element by setting the view-transition-name to, say, disabled and providing this css:
::view-transition-group(disabled),
::view-transition-old(disabled),
::view-transition-new(disabled) {
    animation-duration: 0s !important;
}

